# Audio low latency with Python

Tags: python, audio, latency, asio, low-latency

When using `pygame` audio playback, I notice high latency (>100 ms):

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
sounda = pygame.mixer.Sound("test.wav")

def callback()
    sounda.play()

# callback is called by another function, but I could measure a high latency (> 100ms)
```

Is `pygame` the cause of the latency ? More generally, is **low latency audio playback** possible with Python ?

Example of application : play some .wav files when MIDI messages arrive from a MIDI keyboard. (I want to code a very very basic music sampler).
Of course, the latency will highly depend on the audio interface (ASIO or not ASIO, etc.), but I now want to analyse if low additionnal latency is possible with Python, and if so, which modules are preferred for this purpose.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But StackOverflow is not a good resource for asking for recommendations for tools and libraries. See the help/faq for details.

Comment: Meanwhile, there is a page on [PythonInMusic](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic) on the Python wiki. No idea how up-to-date or comprehensive it is, but there are definitely links to live projects that bind a variety of different native audio libraries in different ways, which should get you started and show you what can be done.

Comment: Yes @abarnert, I completely modified my question in order to ask a precise question (with a reproducible example) on a precise problem related to some implementation. I hope the the 'close' will be avoided, especially when I see similar topics here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448630/low-latency-audio-api-for-android?rq=1

Answer (score 7):

> Is pygame the cause of the latency ?

Probably not.

Pygame is just a wrapper around SDL. In some areas—like this one—it's a very thin wrapper.

But SDL—or, rather, `SDL_mixer`—could easily be the problem.

So, you'll probably need to learn a bit about SDL to use `pygame` for audio beyond the usual gaming-style needs. [Audio with SDL](http://osdl.sourceforge.net/main/documentation/rendering/SDL-audio.html) is a nice overview, although it seems a bit out of date.

---

The first thing to consider is what audio driver you're using. For example, on many linux systems, ALSA can't do low-latency sound, which means that anything you write that ultimately talks to ALSA can't do it either. And if your system is set to use `esd` or some other sound daemon if possible and fall back if necessary, you obviously don't want that here. So, if something like that is your problem, you will have to configure `SDL_mixer` to use a different driver.

---

Assuming the driver can handle it, it definitely is possible to do low-latency sound with `pygame.mixer`/`SDL_mixer`. But it may not work out of the box.

The first thing you'll want to do is pick a smaller buffer size than the default.

Also note that `SDL_mixer` will re-encode your sounds automatically behind your back if they're not in the same sample rate/etc. as the target, which not only adds a bit of latency for the CPU work, it also means the *real* buffer size has nothing to do with the one you think you're using…

An alternative to this is to go around `pygame.mixer`/`SDL_mixer`, do the mixing yourself, and go right to `pygame.sound`/`SDL_sound`. That will still have the same driver issues, but anything that's caused by `SDL_mixer` (like re-encoding) goes away.

If you can't get pygame/SDL to do what you want (e.g., because the only drivers it supports on your system all suck), you will have to use a different library. [PythonInMusic](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic) on the wiki has hundreds of links, and you can also search PyPI. However, you might want to start from the other side—find a C audio library you want to use, then search for Python bindings for it. For example, pyAudio is a relatively thin wrapper around PortAudio, so it rocks if PortAudio's portability, configurability, and performance requirements meet your needs and its API fits your design, but it sucks otherwise.

---

Another place things can go wrong is in your code.

That's obviously not the issue in your case, because all you're doing is giving `pygame.mixer` a pre-made sound. But if you decide you need to, say, pre-convert the sounds and feed buffers into `pygame.sound`, you may run into the issue that Python is slow at looping and slow at arithmetic.

By "slow" I mean on the order of microseconds. Looping once per 20ms buffer is not a problem. Looping once per sample might be. If you're doing any processing, you should consider using NumPy or a dedicated audio library to do the grunt work rather than pure Python.